# Are all the boost dlls and .lib files needed for the boost compilation?

Tags: boost

the total size of the boost dlls and .lib files is coming to around 3.6 gb.I may not use all the dlls and lib files. Assume that I'm only including the Boost/Date and time. Are all the other files needed for the boost compilation ? Are the dlls and the lib files specific to windows and linux ???

Answer (score 0):

You don't need .dlls to compile something at all. Technically, you don't even need .libs to *compile*; only to link, but I'll assume you meant both. You need .dlls to *run* however, so I'm not sure what that buys you.

And yes, .dlls and .libs are specific to the platform. And in the case of .libs, the compiler.

> the total size of the boost dlls and .lib files is coming to around 3.6 gb.

What configurations did you build for? You only need a debug and a release version. If you built a DLL version, then you don't need to also build a static library version (you'll still get .libs though).

My static-library-only variation takes up ~800MB, and I could probably chop that in half, since I see what appears to be duplication in there.